# How to replace a line with something?

Tags: java

So my program needs to overwrite e.g line 5 in a file. Just the 5th line, keep the others.
We don't know what is the content of line 5.
But I have no idea how to do it, can't found anything about how to do this with BufferedWriter and FileWriter.
I can't write there a code, because.. I just don't know how to do it.:/

Comment: Hint: open a reader for reading, and a writer for writing (to a new file). Read one line at a time, keeping a counter for which line you're on. If you're on line 5, perform the replacement before writing it to the new file.

Comment: Okay, but I still can't find how to do it with FileReader?
I see BufferedReader.readLine()
So, for example. when I type br.readLine(), it will read the first line, and when I type it again it will read the second line? I don't know how to use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sample solution could look like this

```
package teststuff;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Btest {

 public static void main(String args[])
     {
     try
         {
         File file = new File("test.txt");
         BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
         String line = "", oldtext = "", fivthLine = "";
         int x=0;
         while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
             {
             oldtext += line + "\r\n";
             if(x == 4)
             {
                 fivthLine = line;
             }
             x++;
         }
         reader.close();

         String newtext = oldtext.replaceAll(fivthLine, "blah blah blah");

         FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("test.txt");
         writer.write(newtext);writer.close();
     }
     catch (IOException ioe)
         {
         ioe.printStackTrace();
     }
 }
}
```

Note that this is a combination of what Emmanuel wrote and [this](https://java.happycodings.com/core-java/code69.html)
It will also replace whats written in the 5th line everywhere on the file, so that another line containing the same content of line 5 will also be overwritten with 
`"blah blah blah"`

Comment: Reading the entire file into memory seems a little inefficient. And if more than one line has the same content you will replace multiple lines.

Comment: This works, but it replaces every lines with the same text. 
Also, I think X should be 1 because when X is 0, it replaces the 6th line.
So if there is a way to do it without replacing all lines which has the same content, then I would be happy if you tell me. If no, I will mark this as the solution.

Comment: You won't learn much if I do the work for you, but I am working on a solution to only replace the 5th line. Initializing x with 1 and checking for x == 5 works aswell, but the way I did it does the same

Comment: I just started learning JAVA, I am also programming in C# and I am very good at it. I know I won't learn if you ,,do the work for me'', but I need it and I don't know how to do it..

Answer (score 0):

by first you can start looking for "How to count lines on a file" like this i found

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-number-lines-words-characters-paragraphs-text-file-using-java/

Then add counter++ each time you pass a line, when (counter == 5) 
then do whatever you need to do..

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple example of replacing a given line in a file:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class LineReplaceTest
{
    public static void main(String... args)
            throws Exception
    {
        int lineToReplace = 5;
        String replacementText = "This is a different line";

        Path input = Paths.get("input.txt");
        Path output = Paths.get("output.txt");

        // Use try-with-resources to ensure our readers & writers are closed
        try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(input);
             BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(output)) {
            String line;
            int lineNumber = 0;

            // While there is a line to read from input...
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                lineNumber++;

                // Write out either the line from the input file or our replacement line
                if (lineNumber == lineToReplace) {
                    writer.write(replacementText);
                } else {
                    writer.write(line);
                }
                writer.newLine();
            }
        }

        // Once we're done, overwrite the input file
        Files.move(output, input);
    }
}
```

It ignores several important things line error handling and platform-specific newline handling, but it should at least get you started.